# Bindear this de una referencia

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un problema al realizar una referencia.

Tengo una clase:

```
class DashboardCard extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.thumbnailContainer = React.createRef(null);
        this.state = {
            loading: true
        };
    }


...
```

En el render, tengo una referencia en un div.

```
 ...
 <div onMouseEnter={this.onOver}>
   <div className="container-view-dashboard" ref={this.thumbnailContainer}>
 ...
```

la función onOver:

```
 onOver(){
    console.log(this.thumbnailContainer.current)
}
```

me da undefined, intuyo que es por el tema del Bind pero no sé como usarlo!

Comment: prueba quitando el null cuando creas una referencia
https://es.reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html no veo que le pase ningun parámetro

Comment: el bind es para que puedas usar el `this` dentro de funciones y que hagan referencia al objeto. con arrow functions, implícitamente ya hace un bind, y no necesitas especificarlo en el constructor. `this.onOver = this.onOver.bind(this)` deberías incluirlo en el constructor

Comment: Si quieres utilziar el bind lo puedes hacer así `this.onOver = this.onOver.bind(this)` en el constructor. @Cheshire +1

Comment: graciass!!!!!!!